# error on wp-login.php wordpress, it is echoing sitename and blog title?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

here is a link hxxp://deleted.com/wp-login.php
I recently removed the www. prefix within the blog settings under site url  and wordpress address because of some redirect loops. But now wordpress has this on the login page.
htaccess is back to standard installation now:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

anyone see what could have caused this output?

Comment: You need to share the whole code of your website so that your question can be answered. However, it's not from javascript, it's from PHP, probably your theme and / or some plugin. Deactivate all plugins and themes and your problem should go away I bet.

Comment: yeah that worked, sometimes I over look the obvious :facepalm:

Comment: Now start to activate one by one to find out which one creates the error output.

Comment: I was able to duplicate this problem on another wordpress install. it is the Point and Stare CMS Functions WordPress plugin

Comment: Its something it does by default for some reason, I'm going to let the author know

Comment: Yes report the bugs. Also place a link with your question here, so it's easier to identify for others, too.

Comment: no problem http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-point-and-stare-cms-functions-siteurl-and-blog-title-output-on-wp-loginphp-when-activated